# C++: &a[2] - &a[1] ==?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-address

`a` is array of integers, if I try to subtract the address value of  `&a[2]  - &a[1] == ?`
what should the result be 4 or 1 ?

**EDIT**: see 4th comment on top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a/) why he says 1 ?? this is why I'm confused I thought it will be 4

**EDIT**: here is a [test](http://codepad.org/bGO7eYxI)

Comment: what do you get when you run it?

Comment: @disioe
: you don't have a compiler? So why are you writing code?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: i'm not I just can't sleep, so I'm reading stackoverflow:)) I program in C# for money. But actually I was going to try it on codepad.org but it's not working now so I decided to ask

Comment: @disioe: erm, what? I know what the answers is, thx.

Comment: @disioe: I'm sorry, I have no idea what you are talking about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`&a[2]` is same as `&(*(a + 2))` (i.e `(a + 2)`) and `&a[1]` is same as `&(*(a + 1))` (i.e. `(a + 1)`). So answer will be 1.

Comment: Thank you very much, I get it now. It was in the thread I read too but somehow I didn't get it. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 6):

Pointer subtraction gives you the difference in *elements*, not bytes. It does not matter what the element type of the array is, the result of `&a[2] - &a[1]` will always be 1, because they are 1 element apart.

Answer (score 4):

It is always 1. The pointer arithmetics are not concerned with the number of bytes that each element has, and this is very useful. Compare these:

```
ptr++;  // go to the next element (correct)
ptr += sizeof *ptr;  // go to the next element (wrong)
```

When you work with arrays you are usually interested in the *elements*, not in the *bytes* comprising them, and that is why pointer arithmetics in C has been defined this way.

Answer (score 3):

The difference must be 1. When you compare pointers you will always get the difference of elements.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is C++, I'm going to assume that you have not overridden the `&` or `*` operators on whatever type `a` is. Minding that, the following is true:

```
&a[2] - &a[1]
(a + 2) - (a + 1)
a + 2 - a - 1
2 - 1
1
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of the answers here (deleted since this answer was posted) clearly had byte* in mind:

```
    int a[10];
    byte * pA2 = (byte*)&a[2];
    byte * pA1 = (byte*)&a[1];
    int sz1 = &a[2] - &a[1];
    int sz2 = pA2 - pA1;
    CString msg;
    msg.Format("int * %d, byte * %d\n", sz1, sz2);
    OutputDebugString(msg);
```

output is:

```
     int * 1, byte * 4
```

Two addresses but depending on the declaration of the variable the addresses are stored in, the difference between the two can be 1 or 4.

Comment: That was my problem, as the question was not in code, I read the question as what is the difference between two addresses, not in terms of "pointer arithmetic".